# Why Does My Kotlin Code Compile In IDEA And Not In Gradle?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a kotlin (test) class with the following import:

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine
```

In IDEA I have added the tools.jar to the SDK classpath.
It runs fine in IDEA but I get errors when running from gradle in `compileTestKotlin`:

```
Unresolved reference: tools
Unresolved reference: VirtualMachine

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:415)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:389)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:251)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:215)
```

How do I get the gradle build to use the `tools.jar`?

The key parts of `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.1"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running the gradle command with the `--scan` option and show us the detailed stacktrace, please.

Comment: You should not add an SDK to the classpath, but use Gradle to include the dependency. IDEA will automatically inspect the build script and add all relevant dependencies to the classpath automatically. So include your dependencies in the build file

Comment: How can you add tools.jar as a dependency?